# is pex really still active?

Tags: .net, pex

Sorry for the beginner question.
My bits are from 2010.
I found a thread that say in 2011 there will be an update.
Did I really find the last bits?
I don't want to ride another dead tool.

Comment: "The Pex and Moles team will release an update of Pex for Visual Studio 11 when the final release becomes available."

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's being integrated into VS 2012.

> [The Fakes Framework](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) in Visual Studio 11 is the next generation of
>   Moles & Stubs, and will eventually replace it.
>
> The Pex and Moles team will release an update of Pex for Visual Studio
>   11 when the final release becomes available. Moles will not developed
>   further so we recommend to migrate to Fakes.

Comment: Moles is being integrated (as Fakes), but Pex isn't. Pex is separate and MS claim it's still being worked on and will be released early 2013, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of activity :-/